# KeyError while accessing dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary named `json_dict` given below.

I need to access the element `==> json_dict['OptionSettings'][3]['Value']`.

I need to access the element using the syntax

`print(json_dict[parameter])`.

When I give a parameter such as

`param="['OptionSettings'][3]['Value']"`  or

`param="'OptionSettings'][3]['Value']"`

I am getting an error like the one below:

`KeyError: "['OptionSettings'][3]['Value']"`.

I tried to use the below solution but it just printed a string

```
str1="json_dict"
print(str1+param)
```

Full Dictionary below:

```
{
        "ApplicationName": "Test",
        "EnvironmentName": "ABC-Nodejs",
        "CNAMEPrefix": "ABC-Neptune",
        "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.1 running Node.js",
        "OptionSettings": [
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
                            "OptionName": "AssociatePublicIpAddress",
                            "Value": "true"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
                            "OptionName": "EnvironmentType",
                            "Value": "LoadBalanced"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
                            "OptionName": "Subnets",
                            "Value": "param1"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                            "OptionName": "SecurityGroups",
                            "Value": "param2"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                            "OptionName": "MinSize",
                            "Value": "1"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                            "OptionName": "MaxSize",
                            "Value": "4"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                            "OptionName": "Availability Zones",
                            "Value": "Any"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                            "OptionName": "Cooldown",
                            "Value": "360"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                            "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile",
                            "Value": "NepRole"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                            "OptionName": "MonitoringInterval",
                            "Value": "5 minutes"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                            "OptionName": "RootVolumeType",
                            "Value": "gp2"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                            "OptionName": "RootVolumeSize",
                            "Value": "10"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics",
                            "OptionName": "Notification Endpoint",
                            "Value": "sunil.kumar2@pb.com"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:hostmanager",
                            "OptionName": "LogPublicationControl",
                            "Value": "false"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
                            "OptionName": "DeploymentPolicy",
                            "Value": "Rolling"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
                            "OptionName": "BatchSizeType",
                            "Value": "Percentage"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
                            "OptionName": "BatchSize",
                            "Value": "100"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
                            "OptionName": "HealthCheckSuccessThreshold",
                            "Value": "Ok"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
                            "OptionName": "IgnoreHealthCheck",
                            "Value": "false"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
                            "OptionName": "Timeout",
                            "Value": "600"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate",
                            "OptionName": "RollingUpdateEnabled",
                            "Value": "false"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
                            "OptionName": "ELBSubnets",
                            "Value": "param3"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elb:loadbalancer",
                            "OptionName": "SecurityGroups",
                            "Value": "param4"
                            },
                           {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elb:loadbalancer",
                            "OptionName": "ManagedSecurityGroup",
                            "Value": "param4"
                            }
                           ]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do that.

When you type `param="['OptionSettings'][3]['Value']"` and then `json_dict[param]`, you are basically asking for the value represented by the key `"['OptionSettings'][3]['Value']"` which does not exists.

You´ll have to navigate through the levels until you get to the last one.

---

But of course, if you need a *one-liner*, you can always create some logic and extract that to a method.

For example, instead of

```
print(json_dict[param]).
```

you could use something like

```
print(get_json_value(json_dict, param))
```

and define a function such as

```
import re

def get_json_value(json_dict, params):
    list_of_params = re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', params)
    #list_of_params = ['OptionSettings', '3', 'Value']

    _ = json_dict
    for elem in list_of_params:
         _ = _[elem]
    return _
```

I haven't tested it but it should work fine. 
(Also, it is just a demo made to guide you through an alternate solution)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
str1="json_dict"
params="['OptionSettings'][3]['Value']"
str2=str1+params
print(eval(str5))
```

Here the use of function ***eval()*** is the key to solve this.